# How to do inferential statistical testing on multiple rows out of only mean and standard deviation data in R?

Tags: r, inference, large-data

Originally, I started out with two .csv files, each 7 GB in size. Once read in into R they each hold about 20 GB of RAM. That is why I calculated the files `df1` and `df2`, which only contain a mean and the standard deviation. Both files have about 8 million rows. The sample size for every mean/standard deviation pair is 157.

`df1`:

```
ID       Mean         Standard deviation
16091071 0.1551044586 0.0120334914
16091086 0.1528095541 0.0125274201
16091147 0.3395656051 0.0186907447
16091154 0.2788547771 0.017261902
16091227 0.250456051 0.0176726877
16091236 0.2776751592 0.0175430484
```

`df2`:

```
ID       Mean         Standard deviation
16091071 0.0999431847 0.0106193089
16091086 0.3864509554 0.0181384583
16091147 0.3864509554 0.0181384583
16091154 0.0999431847 0.0106193089
16091227 0.0999431847 0.0106193089
16091236 0.0999431847 0.0106193089
```

The question now is how to do inferential statistics in R only based on mean and standard deviation data row by row while simultaneously still considering the multiple testing problem.

Comment: What is it that you want to test, and do you have the sample sizes that yielded each mean and standard deviation?

Comment: Oh, sure, of course. I should have given the sample size. For both, df1 and df2, sample size is 157 for every row. At the end, I would like to have 8 million p-values. So whether or not the data sets are significantly different row by row.

Comment: Significantly different how? Also, your problem of dealing with eight-million p-values warrants its own question. Always remember the XKCD on jelly beans: https://xkcd.com/882/.

Comment: I am actually well aware of the jelly bean analogy. In this case though the question behind the statistics should be treated as it is done with the p-values of a genome-wide association study (GWAS) with post-hoc Bonferroni correction.

Comment: Bonferroni on eight million p-values? That means you’re testing at $\alpha= 0.00000000625$ for the usual $5\%$ type I error rate. You’re sure you want to do that?

Comment: Actually yes, this is one of the few things I am indeed sure about. Also an `α` of `0.00000000625` is not that rare in genetics.

Comment: Let’s get back to my previous question: what differences do you want to find?

Comment: Well, the differences between the two sample means. So both, df1 and df2 have ID-columns. I would like to know if the mean in df1 for one ID is significantly different from the mean of the same ID in df2. And I would like to have that information for all the IDs.

Comment: If you just had one ID, what would you do?

Comment: A normal t-test. In the case of multiple IDs an ANOVA. My problem with the ANOVA is that I do not know how to do this in R if I only have already calculated mean and standard deviation data.

Comment: 1) So loop over the IDs and do a t-test for each ID. 2) You don’t have enough information to do ANOVA but can extract that sum of squares information. Then you could loop. (I keep saying to loop. There might be faster implementation, and you can ask about that on Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Of course I also thought about iteration approaches, but I asked the question here, hoping for more performant solutions. Anyway, thank you for your help so far.

Comment: The implementation aspect would be a question for another Stack, probably Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ok, good to know where the specialisation of one Stack ends and where another begins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution with R using your attached dataframes `df1` and `df2`.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attache Paket: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

# Dataframes: 
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(16091071, 16091086, 16091147, 16091154, 16091227, 16091236), 
                  Mean = c(0.1551044586, 0.1528095541, 0.3395656051, 0.2788547771, 
                           0.250456051, 0.2776751592), 
                  Standard_deviation = c(0.0120334914, 0.0125274201, 0.0186907447, 
                                         0.017261902, 0.0176726877, 0.0175430484)
)

df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(16091071, 16091086, 16091147, 16091154, 16091227, 16091236), 
                  Mean = c(0.0999431847, 0.3864509554, 0.3864509554, 0.0999431847,
                           0.0999431847, 0.0999431847), 
                  Standard_deviation = c(0.0106193089, 0.0181384583, 0.0181384583,
                                         0.0106193089, 0.0106193089, 0.0106193089)
)

# Merging: 
df_all <- dplyr::left_join(df1, df2, by = "ID")

# Function to perform t.test for given means and standard deviations: 
# mean_x: mean of sample x
# mean_y: mean of sample y
# sd_x: standard deviation of sample x
# sd_y: standard deviation of sample y 
# n_x: sample size of sample x
# n_y: sample size of sample y
# mu: difference in means 
# alpha: significance level; default is 0.05.. important for F Test of variance comparison. 
t.test_new <- function(mean_x, mean_y, sd_x, sd_y, n_x, n_y, mu = 0, alpha = 0.05)
{
  
  # test for equal variances: 
  F_test <- sd_x^2 / sd_y^2
  F_crit <- qf(p = c(alpha / 2, 1 - alpha / 2), df1 = n_x - 1, df2 = n_y - 1)
  
  if(dplyr::between(F_test, F_crit[1], F_crit[2])) var_equal <- TRUE else var_equal <- FALSE 
  
  if (var_equal) {
   sd_test <- sqrt( (((n_x - 1) * sd_x^2 + (n_y - 1) * sd_y^2) / (n_x + n_y - 2)) * ((n_x + n_y) / (n_x * n_y)) ) 
   dof <- n_x + n_y - 2
  } else {
    sd_test <- sqrt((sd_x^2 / n_x) + (sd_y^2 / n_y))
    c_welch <- (sd_x^2 / n_x) / ((sd_x^2 / n_x) + (sd_y^2 / n_y))
    dof <- 1 / ( (c_welch^2 / (n_x - 1)) + ((1 - c_welch)^2 / (n_y - 1)) )
  }

  t_test <- ((mean_x - mean_y) - mu) / sd_test
  output <- c(
    statistic = t_test, 
    parameter = dof, 
    p.value = 2 * pt(q = abs(t_test), df = dof, lower.tail = FALSE), 
    stderr = sd_test
  )
  output
}


test_mat <- t(sapply(1:nrow(df_all), FUN = function(i) {
  t.test_new(mean_x = df_all[i, ]$Mean.x, mean_y = df_all[i, ]$Mean.y, 
                 sd_x = df_all[i, ]$Standard_deviation.x, 
             sd_y = df_all[i, ]$Standard_deviation.y, 
                 n_x = 157, n_y = 157
  )}
))

final_df <- dplyr::bind_cols(df_all, as.data.frame(test_mat))
final_df
#>         ID    Mean.x Standard_deviation.x     Mean.y Standard_deviation.y
#> 1 16091071 0.1551045           0.01203349 0.09994318           0.01061931
#> 2 16091086 0.1528096           0.01252742 0.38645096           0.01813846
#> 3 16091147 0.3395656           0.01869074 0.38645096           0.01813846
#> 4 16091154 0.2788548           0.01726190 0.09994318           0.01061931
#> 5 16091227 0.2504561           0.01767269 0.09994318           0.01061931
#> 6 16091236 0.2776752           0.01754305 0.09994318           0.01061931
#>    statistic parameter       p.value      stderr
#> 1   43.06580  312.0000 2.469975e-133 0.001280860
#> 2 -132.80314  277.2394 5.436359e-253 0.001759306
#> 3  -22.55594  312.0000  1.686821e-67 0.002078626
#> 4  110.61225  259.2849 3.304864e-220 0.001617466
#> 5   91.47052  255.6602 2.418289e-197 0.001645479
#> 6  108.59699  256.7911 1.257999e-216 0.001636620
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Wow, thank you! That is a great solution!